# Add prototype/Method to jQuery val();

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, prototype

So I'm sending the values of a bunch of checkboxes to my database, but my database stores the values as tinyint's and jQuery `val()` returns boolean `true` or `false`, which is then sent as a string to the server.

I would like to write a function that changes the `true` or `false` value to a `1` or `0`, respectively. So that I could use it in this manner:

```
var value = $("#checkboxID").val().booleanToInt();
console.log(value) //returns integer;
```

I DO NOT need help writing the function, as it will be trivial, I just dont know HOW to implement this behavior/syntax....

I've done something similar with dates, by modifying the `Date.prototype` so that I could quickly turn my local dates to UTC format like so:

```
var utcDate = localDate.toUtcFormat();
```

Just don't know how to do it for the checkbox scenario.

Comment: hmm... doesn't .val() return "on" and "off" for checkboxes, unless you specify otherwise in the value?

Comment: Maybe for jqueryui checkboxes, Im using a different widget library that returns true or false.

Comment: Is it boolean true, or string true.

Comment: boolean true. only string after sent to server

Comment: It's no different than what you did with dates. `Boolean.prototype.foo = function(){console.log('worky');}; true.foo();`

Comment: [this is another XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @KevinB thanks that's what I was looking for, didnt know you could add prototypes to a Boolean object like that, thanks

Comment: afaik, there aren't any javascript objects that you can't add to in that way. I'm not saying that's the correct way to solve this problem though, personally, i'd solve this on the server side, or by extending the widget that is giving you the boolean value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your input is coming in as `true` and `false`, you don't need to corrupt any built-in prototypes, the simple solution is to just cast the boolean to a number:

```
var value = Number($('#checkboxID').val());
//or the shortcut:
var value = +$("#checkboxID").val();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much easier than modifying the prototypes!

Comment: or `var value = $('#checkboxID').val()?1:0` which seems worst :)